# How to search a txt file using 2 sets of user input, then print the associated line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I appreciate anyone taking time to help me with this. Basically I'm trying to write a script that takes 2 sets of user input stored in variables, and then searches a txt file with the users input. Then once it finds a line that matches, prints it.

In this example, I would like to search the txt file using the user input stored in "area" and "name". For example, someone puts "test02" for the area variable, then "STT40" for the name variable. It would then print off the second line in the txt file. Thanks again for your time!

Example of file.txt

test01 | STT50 | A | Floor 1 | Row 2 
test02 | STT40 | B | Floor 2 | Row 3 
test14 | STT30 | C | Floor 3 | Row 4

Script: (Still in progress, just wanted to put what I had so far)

```
global area = input("Please insert your test number: ")

global name = input("Please insert STT name: ")

def spp():
  with open("file.txt", "r") as f:

    for line in f.readlines():

      if line.startswith(name):

        print(line)
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you are trying to do

```
def spp():
  with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith(area) and name in line:
            print(line)
```